# NFS won't mount on boot anymore in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, nfs

There are a few **NFS won't mount on boot!** questions on AskUbuntu already, but I never had any problems 'till I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10.

The NFS entries in my fstab are as follows:

```
192.168.1.2:/media/tardis /media/tardis nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,fsc,actimeo=1800 0 0
192.168.1.2:/media/bridge /media/bridge nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,fsc,actimeo=1800 0 0
192.168.1.2:/media/scratch /media/scratch nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,fsc,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

This is what I get in the `syslog`:

```
Nov 28 12:50:17 stormwind systemd[1]: Mounting /media/tardis...
Nov 28 12:50:17 stormwind systemd[1]: media-tardis.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Nov 28 12:50:17 stormwind systemd[1]: Failed to mount /media/tardis.
Nov 28 12:50:17 stormwind systemd[1]: media-tardis.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

Any idea what changed and how to solve it?

Comment: I really doubt this would help but, just in case, try changing the `nfs` value in your fstab file to `nfs4`. Also try running `sudo mount 192.168.1.2:/media/tardis /media/tardis` does that work? Any error messages?

Comment: Right, forgot to mention: running `sudo mount -a` just works after booting. I'll try the nfs4 option